# Rendering polygons outside latitudes [85,-85] in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, cesium

I have some polygons I am drawing on an OpenLayers 3 map.

Some of these are above latitude 85, and used to be rendered fine with OpenLayers 3 v3.15.1: https://jsfiddle.net/adlerhn/98mn4w5z/

However, in the latest version of OpenLayers (3.20.0), there is clipping in place, and polygons outside the extent of the map are not rendered: https://jsfiddle.net/adlerhn/xt5m1o6d/

The reason I am trying to render outside of the bounds of a map is because I am using ol3-cesium to render into a 3D globe, and in there you can see latitudes between 85 and 90, which would otherwise appear as a gap on the top.

I have tried adding the extent property to the vector layer, but I haven't got any result.

```
var extent = ol.proj.get("EPSG:4326").getExtent();

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    map: this.map,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [new ol.Feature({
            geometry: geometry
        })]
    }),
    extent: extent,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.5)'
        })
      })
});
```

How can I get OpenLayers to render outside the extent of the map?

Answer (score 2):

Latitudes beyond +/- 85.06 degrees cannot be rendered using Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) as projection, which is the default. Just configure your map's view with a projection like EPSG:4326, and you will be fine:

```
new ol.Map({
  /* ... */
  view: new ol.View({
    /* ... */
    projection: 'EPSG:4326'
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick, even though of course it affects the appearance of the map. I wonder which projection would users prefer. Also, on a separate note, this projection seems to cause an [issue](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3-cesium/issues/429) when used with ol3-cesium.